Is it true to claim that every ciphertext can be generated by every plaintext through a key in a perfectly secret encryption scheme?
I'm solving the exercises from the book "Introduction to Modern Cryptography" and this question popped up in my mind. What I'm asking is: in a perfectly secret encryption scheme, for every plaintext, is it possible to generate all possible ciphertexts?

By definition, all possible ciphertext can be generated. But that might not be what you wanted to ask.

Ciphertext space can be easily defined to be larger than plaintext space. In perfect secrecy definition/game we talk about possible ciphertext not the ciphertext space.
